# Why does background image not show behind text?

Tags: html

I have a [site](http://AskACarPro.com) with a splash page which has a background image.  There is text on top of the image.  The issue is that the background of the text is white, instead of being transparent so the image shows through.

How do I set the background to transparent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you've set your background image in the styling of the `<html>` tag, which sits underneath the `<body>` tag, and `<body>` is styled with `background-color:#fff`.

I suggest you move the background image to the `<body>` tag, replacing the `background-color:#fff` with it. In other words, move the `class="backgroundImage"` attribute from `<html>` to `<body>`.

As a general note, `transparent` is the default value for `background-color`, so if something is not transparent, it's because there's some code somewhere that's nixing that transparency.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add to the class ".message" -> background-color:transparent;